# Create New Record from Lookup

Tags: junction-object

I have a junction object with a lookup to ERN and Policy. When I lookup the ERN on the junction object I want to be able to create a new ERN in the Lookup dialog if the ERN doesn't exist yet.
ERN is simply a number, so it would only require one field to be filled in. I assume this is a simple config issue.
Tia.[image: Create New]

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Setup -> User Interface, there is an option called "Show Quick Create". Once that is selected, the lookup dialogs would show the New button.

Update:
My apologies, the New button is only available on some standard objects. See if the solution mentioned in the following post would work for you. [How to Add new button on custom object lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008jsoIAA)

Comment: I have enabled this, but the New button does not show.

Comment: My apologies, the New button is only available on some standard objects. See if the solution mentioned in the following post would work for you. [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008jsoIAA)

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger to create the ERN number as soon as you save the junction record. The trigger creates an auto number on ERN object and populates the lookup on this record only if ERN is "NULL when you save it.

PS. The issue is that we current cant assign default values to lookup. so we have to use triggers. 
Also, if you still wish to have a "new" functionality on the window, apex may (read may) be able to help you. I am not a developer so wont comment further on using apex.

Comment: I need to enter a specific number in the ERN object, I cannot be any number, so this won't work unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have a logic sequence to that number? or any other logic that you use to fill that num?

Comment: An ERN is an employer reference number and it has no logical sequence.

Comment: So let me ask you- how do you know what is an ERN when you manually enter it?

Comment: Well, just like you know a person's phone number, I know the ERNs of my clients, but there is still no logical sequence to it. Instead of using Auto number for the ERN object, we use Text and use the ERN as a unique identifier.

Comment: got it - create a trigger that works "before insert" on junction object. So if you enter an ERN num that doesnt have a lookup, the trigger tries to interest a record on the ERN table and then save this record.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19465/discussion-between-mann-and-lily).