# How to provide a "New" option for a lookup field in layout-based UI

Tags: junction-object

I have a junction object `PolicyERN`, which links `Policy` and `ERN`.

When a Policy was created, I want to add ERNs to it. This opens the junction object detail page (see screenshot).

[image: PolicyERN]

I need a way to let the user add a new ERN if they cannot find the correct existing one. I thought about adding a detail button, but it seems that they are not shown when I'm in edit mode.

Any ideas? Tia.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to use Visualforce for this (unless someone has a way to do it with layout-based UI), though as there are only 2 fields in the page that shouldn't be too bad. Then you can put a "New" button or link next to the ERN field. The Vsualforce page will need to extend the standard controller so you can use it to replace the "New" and "Edit" actions for PolicyERN.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to see a New button on the lookup window. Will that not work for you?

> EDIT: My apologies, the New button is only available on some standard objects. See if the solution mentioned in the following post would work for you. [How to Add new button on custom object lookup](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008jsoIAA)

Comment: Note that the New button is only displayed if "Show Quick Create" is selected in Setup -> User Interface section.

Comment: You answer [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60012/create-new-record-from-lookup/60115#60115) says the new is only available for some standard objects and this is not a standard object.

Comment: Yes, my apologies for that. I updated that answer later and did not update this one. Thanks for correcting me.